# Will we observe the laws of Orlah when moshiach comes?

Tags: ymoth-hamoshiach

B"H

I've been thinking on the subject of Orlah in the times of the Garden of Aydin, that if it was expected that Adam shouldn't have sinned, and if the Torah existed before creation (meaning it was expected that it should anyways be done even if Adam didn't sin), and if all of the trees etc. grew to full maturity right away (see Rashi beginning of bereishis) how would there ever have been a possibility of observing Orlah, assuming Adam wouldn't have sinned and we would have gotten the Torah then etc.?

A practical application of this is when moshiach comes, when it says that the trees will once again grow the same time they are planted to a mature state (as well as pregnant woman giving birth right away, harah viyoyledes yawchdawv, I think it's on Shabbos around daf 22 or so), will we still wait 3 years to eat of the fruit?

And similarly what about the laws of kilayim and other produce which only apply once the plants grow a third of the way (see rambam Sefer zeraim)?

Blessings and success

Comment: Note that full maturity has little or nothing to do with it. If a fully grown tree is uprooted, without enough dirt around its roots for it to live on, then when it's replanted, it's subject to orlah again ([Shulchan Aruch, Yoreh Deah 294:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.294.19?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)).

Comment: @meir oh I didn't know that, is that also if the dirt is taken with it? Either way them perhaps there would still be Orlah if it's fully mature

Comment: If there's enough dirt with it to live on, then no, orlah doesn't apply. See that se'if in Shulchan Aruch.

Comment: Also, maturity of the tree has nothing to do with when the fruit first appears. You also don’t learn out halacha from Gan Eden. According to one midrash Adam had physical relations with all the animals. That is prohibited. Additionally, at least in the beginning of the days of Moshiach the world will be conducted in the natural order we experience now. And Moshiach will bring us to fulfill all the mitzvot in the fullest way possible like Rambam and others hold.

Comment: @YaacovDeane ah yes, but what is considered "the natural order"? I've seen in meluket that when it says the "natural order" it refers to the revelation of the infinite light that existed before creation, in the world itself, since that's still considered "natural", since it has at least a relation to the world, and is what the world was built on, as well as the world being elevated back to the state it was when it was "created perfect" -- in it's fully natural state, like in the garden of aydin, in other words, nowadays is not natural, in the garden of aydin, it was the *real* natural order

Comment: @YaacovDeane as opposed to the second phase that is a "cheedoosh bimaweesay birayshees", which represents a revelation of a deeper aspect of the infinite light that didn't even shine before the world was created, a *new* revelation of the infinite light, the essential light, a "cheedoosh"...

Comment: @bluejayke Concerning your 1st preceding comment, that is why I said, “At least in the beginning of the days of Moshiach...”. The approach of Rambam and the Rebbe is that of Meir Ibn Gabbai. Regarding your 2nd comment, that idea as taught by the Rebbe is not pertaining to the days of Moshiach.

Comment: @yaakov even at the beginning it says there will be the infinite light just like gawn Aydin